создание окон при помощи PyQt5[Python]
напишите мне код для создания нового,пустого окна в PyQt5
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication,QWidget
main_win = QWidget()
main_win.resize(500,500)
app = QApplication([])
main_win.show
app.exec_()
class New_win(QWidget)
...


Добро пожаловать на сайт ru.SO! рекомендую ознакомиться со справкой => https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask //на ru.SO не пишут код за кого то, но отвечают на вопросы. Пожалуйста [edit] ваш вопрос, и укажите что именно у вас не получается.

https://zetcode.com/gui/pyqt5/firstprograms/
